# How do I modify the results of a database query from an Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, meanjs

I'm new to Angular and MEAN.js and I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate data that is being returned from  my controller ( client side ) before the data gets to the view. i have a function in my controler that makes the query to the database.

```
    $scope.getDataPoints = function() {
        $scope.datapoints = Datapoints.query();
        console.log($scope.datapoints.length);
        console.log($scope.datapoints);

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datapoints.length; i++) {
           console.log($scope.datapoints[i].thevalue + ",");
            console.log($scope.datapoints[i].variant + ",");
        }

    };
```

As expected query returns a promise, so the loop does not execute. How do I capture, manipulate ( using lodash ) and then provide the data to the view ?

Answer (score 0):

If it returns a promise

```
 $scope.getDataPoints = function() {
   Datapoints.query()
     .then(function(response) {
       // Don't know what this resolves with, assuming response.data is what you would want
       $scope.datapoints = response.data;

       console.log($scope.datapoints.length);
       console.log($scope.datapoints);

       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datapoints.length; i++) {
         console.log($scope.datapoints[i].thevalue + ",");
         console.log($scope.datapoints[i].variant + ",");
       }
     });
 }
```

Comment: it complains that Datapoints.query(...).then is not a function

Comment: If this is AngularJS and .query() returns an $http or $q promise, then should be present. Confirm that your function actually *returns* a promise